# Hibernate - filter Single Column data using date where clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Lets say One table ABC having two column i.e. ID & CREATED_DATE

I want to fetch those ID which is created lets say `'09-11-2017'` and `'09-17-2017'`

Below SQL query working fine but I want to implement same logic using hibernate.

```
select ID from ABC where between TO_DATE('09-11-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY')  AND TO_DATE('09-17-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

My code is not working.

```
public List getData(final Date startDate, final Date endDate){

    String sqlString = "select ID from ABC where CREATED_DATE between :startDate and :endDate";
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlString);
    query.setParameter(CREATED_DATE);
    return query.list();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing End date parameter :

```
query.setParameter(CREATED_DATE, startDate);
query.setParameter(END_DATE, endDate);
```

Comment: Thank you @user7294900. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It not work because you don't set the correct parameters :

```
String sqlString = "select ID from ABC where CREATED_DATE between :startDate and :endDate";
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlString);
query.setParameter("startDate ", start_date);
query.setParameter("endDate", end_date);
return query.list();
```

Comment: second parameter is endDate

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L. I just start read the online documents to learn more. You guys are rock

Answer (score 2):

The parameters must match the string on the query

Try this:

```
public List getData(final Date startDate, final Date endDate){

    String sqlString = "select ID from ABC where CREATED_DATE between :startDate and :endDate";
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlString);
    query.setParameter("startDate",startDate);
    query.setParameter("endDate",endDate);
    return query.list();
}
```

--

pscar13